# How to get less than or greater than value based on specific column in mongodb using node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Suppose that,I have a product collection named productCollection.How can i get all those products where the product's amount is less than a specific amount?What is the query

Comment: I'm sure you know about `"$lt"`.  What does your collection look like?  Please show some sample documents and the queries you have tried.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.